# How can I inject a property value into a Spring Bean which was configured using annotations?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a bunch of Spring beans which are picked up from the classpath via annotations, e.g.

```
@Repository("personDao")
public class PersonDaoImpl extends AbstractDaoImpl implements PersonDao {
    // Implementation omitted
}
```

In the Spring XML file, there's a [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) defined:

```xml
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" 
  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/app.properties" />
</bean>
```

I want to inject one of the properties from app.properites into the bean shown above. I can't simply do something like

```xml
<bean class="com.example.PersonDaoImpl">
    <property name="maxResults" value="${results.max}"/>
</bean>
```

Because PersonDaoImpl does not feature in the Spring XML file (it is picked up from the classpath via annotations). I've got as far as the following:

```
@Repository("personDao")
public class PersonDaoImpl extends AbstractDaoImpl implements PersonDao {

    @Resource(name = "propertyConfigurer")
    protected void setProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc) {
    // Now how do I access results.max? 
    }
}
```

But it's not clear to me how I access the property I'm interested in from `ppc`?

Comment: I've asked essentially the same question, although in a slightly different scenario: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310271/injecting-beans-into-a-class-outside-the-spring-managed-context. So far, no one has been able to answer it.

Comment: Please note that as of Spring 3.1, `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` is no longer the recommended class. Prefer `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` instead. In any case, you can use the shorter XML definition `<context:property-placeholder />`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28756014/how-to-configure-dynamic-properties-while-using-spring-boot

Answer (score 307, accepted):

You can do this in Spring 3 using EL support. Example:

```
@Value("#{systemProperties.databaseName}")
public void setDatabaseName(String dbName) { ... }

@Value("#{strategyBean.databaseKeyGenerator}")
public void setKeyGenerator(KeyGenerator kg) { ... }
```

`systemProperties` is an implicit object and `strategyBean` is a bean name.

One more example, which works when you want to grab a property from a `Properties` object. It also shows that you can apply `@Value` to fields:

```
@Value("#{myProperties['github.oauth.clientId']}")
private String githubOauthClientId;
```

Here is a [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20170609134527/http://springinpractice.com/2008/12/02/new-stuff-in-spring-30/) I wrote about this for a little more info.

Comment: Is `systemProperties` simply `System.getProperties()`? I guess if I want to inject my own properties into a Spring bean I need to define a `<bean id="appProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">` then read values from that into another bean using something like `@Value("#{appProperties.databaseName}")`

Comment: Make sure to note from max's answer that you can also use placeholders in the expressions ${db.doStuff}, then you don't need a PropertiesFactoryBean, just a placeholderConfigurer

Comment: You can add your own properties using util:properties; e.g., <util:properties id="config" location="classpath:/spring/environment.properties" />. See the edited answer for how to get the value. (I realize this is probably too late to have been helpful to Don, but others will hopefully benefit.)

Comment: It only worked for me when I used util:properties in my appname-servlet.xml file. Using propertyConfigurer defined in my applicationContext.xml (not the Spring MVC one) didn't work.

Comment: For a little further reading, that elaborates on some of this, check out this SOF question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425795/injecting-properties-using-spring-annotation-value/6430610#6430610

Comment: Anyway to add the import statements on a java example?  #recurringTheme

Answer (score 153):

Personally I love this new way in Spring 3.0 [from the docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.html):

```
private @Value("${propertyName}") String propertyField;
```

No getters or setters!

With the properties being loaded via the config:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
      p:location="classpath:propertyFile.properties" name="propertiesBean"/>
```

To further my glee I can even control click on the EL expression in IntelliJ and it brings me to the property definition!

There's also the totally **non xml version**:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:propertyFile.properties")
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
```

Comment: make sure and add in the namespace uri xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" to use the p: prefixed attributes.

Comment: Why this methods works in a test context but not in the main context ?

Comment: sigh, I spent hour trying to make annotations-only approach work and discovered what is missing only after reading this answer-  declaration of a magical static bean PropertySauceYadaYada. Spring love!

Comment: @barrymac hey barry, do U know what is the difference between @Value(#{...}) and @Value(${...}).

Thank you

Comment: This works for me. Only one tip: annotation @Component is required.

Comment: How does Spring instantiate that private field under the hood if it doesn't have a setter?

Comment: It works with application.properties but I couldn't make it working with application.yaml

Answer (score 123):

There is a new annotation `@Value` in *Spring 3.0.0M3*. `@Value` support not only `#{...}` expressions but `${...}` placeholders as well

Comment: +1 If an example helps, here it is - @Value(value="#{'${server.env}'}") or simply @Value("#{'${server.env}'}")

Answer (score 31):

`<context:property-placeholder ... />` is the XML equivalent to the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.

Example:
applicationContext.xml

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:test.properties"/>
```

Component class

```
 private @Value("${propertyName}") String propertyField;
```

Comment: For me, this worked only if autowiring is enabled via
`<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.package" />`
For reference, I'm using spring via the `ApplicationContext`, not in a web context.

Answer (score 15):

Another alternative is to add the appProperties bean shown below:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"   
  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/app.properties" />
</bean> 


<bean id="appProperties" 
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="singleton" value="true"/>

        <property name="properties">
                <props>
                        <prop key="results.max">${results.max}</prop>
                </props>
        </property>
</bean>
```

When retrieved, this bean can be cast to a `java.util.Properties` which will contain a property named `results.max` whose value is read from `app.properties`. Again, this bean can be dependency injected (as an instance of java.util.Properties) into any class via the @Resource annotation.

Personally, I prefer this solution (to the other I proposed), as you can limit exactly which properties are exposed by appProperties, and don't need to read app.properties twice.

Comment: Works for me, too. But is there no other way to acces the properties from a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer via the @Value annotation (when using multiple PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in several congif XML files.)?

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned `@Value` does the job and it is quite flexible as you can have spring EL in it.

Here are some examples, which could be helpful:

```
//Build and array from comma separated parameters 
//Like currency.codes.list=10,11,12,13
@Value("#{'${currency.codes.list}'.split(',')}") 
private List<String> currencyTypes;
```

Another to get a `set` from a `list`

```
//If you have a list of some objects like (List<BranchVO>) 
//and the BranchVO has areaCode,cityCode,...
//You can easily make a set or areaCodes as below
@Value("#{BranchList.![areaCode]}") 
private Set<String> areas;
```

You can also set values for primitive types.

```
@Value("${amount.limit}")
private int amountLimit;
```

You can call static methods:

```
@Value("#{T(foo.bar).isSecurityEnabled()}")
private boolean securityEnabled;
```

You can have logic

```
@Value("#{T(foo.bar).isSecurityEnabled() ? '${security.logo.path}' : '${default.logo.path}'}")
private String logoPath;
```

Answer (score 9):

I need to have two properties files, one for production and an override for development (that will not be deployed).

To have both, a Properties Bean that can be autowired and a PropertyConfigurer, you can write:

```
<bean id="appProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="singleton" value="true" />

    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:live.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:development.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and reference the Properties Bean in the PropertyConfigurer

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="properties" ref="appProperties" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 8):

You also can annotate you class:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/com/myProject/config/properties/database.properties")
```

And have a variable like this:

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;
```

Now you can access to all your properties in this way:

```
env.getProperty("database.connection.driver")
```

Answer (score 7):

Before we get Spring 3 - which allows you to inject property constants directly into your beans using annotations - I wrote a sub-class of the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean that does the same thing. So, you can mark up your property setters and Spring will autowire your properties into your beans like so:

```
@Property(key="property.key", defaultValue="default")
public void setProperty(String property) {
    this.property = property;
}
```

The Annotation is as follows:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) 
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
public @interface Property {
    String key();
    String defaultValue() default "";
}
```

The PropertyAnnotationAndPlaceholderConfigurer is as follows:

```
public class PropertyAnnotationAndPlaceholderConfigurer extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PropertyAnnotationAndPlaceholderConfigurer.class);

    @Override
    protected void processProperties(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory, Properties properties) throws BeansException {
        super.processProperties(beanFactory, properties);

        for (String name : beanFactory.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            MutablePropertyValues mpv = beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(name).getPropertyValues();
            Class clazz = beanFactory.getType(name);

            if(log.isDebugEnabled()) log.debug("Configuring properties for bean="+name+"["+clazz+"]");

            if(clazz != null) {
                for (PropertyDescriptor property : BeanUtils.getPropertyDescriptors(clazz)) {
                    Method setter = property.getWriteMethod();
                    Method getter = property.getReadMethod();
                    Property annotation = null;
                    if(setter != null && setter.isAnnotationPresent(Property.class)) {
                        annotation = setter.getAnnotation(Property.class);
                    } else if(setter != null && getter != null && getter.isAnnotationPresent(Property.class)) {
                        annotation = getter.getAnnotation(Property.class);
                    }
                    if(annotation != null) {
                        String value = resolvePlaceholder(annotation.key(), properties, SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_FALLBACK);
                        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(value)) {
                            value = annotation.defaultValue();
                        }
                        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(value)) {
                            throw new BeanConfigurationException("No such property=["+annotation.key()+"] found in properties.");
                        }
                        if(log.isDebugEnabled()) log.debug("setting property=["+clazz.getName()+"."+property.getName()+"] value=["+annotation.key()+"="+value+"]");
                        mpv.addPropertyValue(property.getName(), value);
                    }
                }

                for(Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
                    if(log.isDebugEnabled()) log.debug("examining field=["+clazz.getName()+"."+field.getName()+"]");
                    if(field.isAnnotationPresent(Property.class)) {
                        Property annotation = field.getAnnotation(Property.class);
                        PropertyDescriptor property = BeanUtils.getPropertyDescriptor(clazz, field.getName());

                        if(property.getWriteMethod() == null) {
                            throw new BeanConfigurationException("setter for property=["+clazz.getName()+"."+field.getName()+"] not available.");
                        }

                        Object value = resolvePlaceholder(annotation.key(), properties, SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_FALLBACK);
                        if(value == null) {
                            value = annotation.defaultValue();
                        }
                        if(value == null) {
                            throw new BeanConfigurationException("No such property=["+annotation.key()+"] found in properties.");
                        }
                        if(log.isDebugEnabled()) log.debug("setting property=["+clazz.getName()+"."+field.getName()+"] value=["+annotation.key()+"="+value+"]");
                        mpv.addPropertyValue(property.getName(), value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Feel free to modify to taste

Comment: Please note, that I have created a new project for the above:

http://code.google.com/p/spring-property-annotations/

Answer (score 7):

Spring way:
`private @Value("${propertyName}") 
String propertyField;`

is a new way to inject the value using Spring's "PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" class. 
Another way is to call

```
java.util.Properties props = System.getProperties().getProperty("propertyName");
```

Note: For @Value, you can not use **static** propertyField, it should be non-static only, otherwise it returns null. To fix it a non static setter is created for the static field and @Value is applied above that setter.

Answer (score 5):

A possible solutions is to declare a second bean which reads from the same properties file:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/app.properties" />
</bean> 

<util:properties id="appProperties" location="classpath:/WEB-INF/app.properties"/>
```

The bean named 'appProperties' is of type java.util.Properties and can be dependency injected using the @Resource attruibute shown above.

Answer (score 4):

If you are stuck using Spring 2.5 you could define a bean for each of your properties and inject them using qualifiers.  Like this:

```
  <bean id="someFile" class="java.io.File">
    <constructor-arg value="${someFile}"/>
  </bean>
```

and

```
@Service
public class Thing
      public Thing(@Qualifier("someFile") File someFile) {
...
```

Its not super readable but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 2):

**Autowiring Property Values into Spring Beans:**

Most people know that you can use @Autowired to tell Spring to inject one object into another when it loads your application context. A lesser known nugget of information is that you can also use the @Value annotation to inject values from a property file into a bean’s attributes.
see this post for more info...

[new stuff in Spring 3.0](http://springinpractice.com/2008/12/02/new-stuff-in-spring-30/)
|| [autowiring bean values](http://java.dzone.com/articles/autowiring-property-values)
||[autowiring property values in spring](http://www.captaindebug.com/2011/10/autowiring-property-values-into-spring_28.html)

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was @Lucky's answer, and specifically, the line

```
AutowiredFakaSource fakeDataSource = ctx.getBean(AutowiredFakaSource.class);
```

from [the Captain Debug page](http://www.captaindebug.com/2011/10/autowiring-property-values-into-spring_28.html)

that fixed my problem. I have an ApplicationContext-based app running from the command-line, and judging by a number of the comments on SO, Spring wires up these differently to MVC-based apps.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's most convenient way to inject properties into bean is setter method.

Example:

```
package org.some.beans;

public class MyBean {
    Long id;
    String name;

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Bean xml definition:

```
<bean id="Bean1" class="org.some.beans.MyBean">
    <property name="id" value="1"/>
    <property name="name" value="MyBean"/>
</bean>
```

For every named `property` method `setProperty(value)` will be invoked.

This way is especially helpful if you need more than one bean based on one implementation.

For example, if we define one more bean in xml:

```
<bean id="Bean2" class="org.some.beans.MyBean">
    <property name="id" value="2"/>
    <property name="name" value="EnotherBean"/>
</bean>
```

Then code like this:

```
MyBean b1 = appContext.getBean("Bean1");
System.out.println("Bean id = " + b1.getId() + " name = " + b1.getName());
MyBean b2 = appContext.getBean("Bean2");
System.out.println("Bean id = " + b2.getId() + " name = " + b2.getName());
```

Will print

```
Bean id = 1 name = MyBean
Bean id = 2 name = AnotherBean
```

So, in your case it should look like this:

```
@Repository("personDao")
public class PersonDaoImpl extends AbstractDaoImpl implements PersonDao {

    Long maxResults;

    public void setMaxResults(Long maxResults) {
        this.maxResults = maxResults;
    }

    // Now use maxResults value in your code, it will be injected on Bean creation
    public void someMethod(Long results) {
        if (results < maxResults) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need more Flexibility for the configurations, try the Settings4jPlaceholderConfigurer:
http://settings4j.sourceforge.net/currentrelease/configSpringPlaceholder.html

In our application we use:

- Preferences to configure the PreProd- and Prod-System
- Preferences and JNDI Environment variables (JNDI overwrites the preferences) for "mvn jetty:run"
- System Properties for UnitTests (@BeforeClass annotation)

The default order which key-value-Source is checked first, is described in:
http://settings4j.sourceforge.net/currentrelease/configDefault.html 
It can be customized with a settings4j.xml (accurate to log4j.xml) in your classpath.

Let me know your opinion: settings4j-user@lists.sourceforge.net

with friendly regards, 
Harald

Answer (score -1):

Use Spring's "PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" class

A simple example showing property file read dynamically as bean's property

```
<bean id="placeholderConfig"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/classes/config_properties/dev/database.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property> 
</bean>

<bean id="devDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${dev.app.jdbc.driver}"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${dev.app.jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="user" value="${dev.app.jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${dev.app.jdbc.password}"/>
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="3"/>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10"/>
    <property name="maxStatementsPerConnection" value="11000"/>
    <property name="numHelperThreads" value="8"/>
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="300"/>
    <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 0"/>
</bean>
```

Property File

dev.app.jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

dev.app.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/addvertisement

dev.app.jdbc.username=root

dev.app.jdbc.password=root

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way in Spring 5 is to use `@ConfigurationProperties` here is example
https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-configurationproperties-example/

Answer (score -1):

use @PropertySource("classpath:XX.properties") on your configuration class.
XX=file_name
[image]