# Wiring Spring bean through annotations and xml context

Tags: java, spring, annotations, ejb

I've got the following Spring service:

```
@Service
public class Worker {

    @Autowired
    private MyExecutorService executor;

    @Autowired
    private IRun run;

    private Integer startingPoint;

    // Remainder omitted

}
```

Now I want to load the `startingPoint` through a `.properties` file.

Is it possible to wire a Spring service through annotations and an xml context at the same time?

Maybe something like this:

```
<bean id="worker" class="Worker">
    <property name="startingPoint">
        <value>${startingPoint}</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

`startingPoint` is wired through the xml context file, everything else gets auto-wired.

Comment: Just on a side note, it is possible to write a property through an annotation, you can do this with the [@Value annotation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317687/inject-property-value-into-spring-bean).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes!  This is most definitely possible, and it's a good way to go if you can't get around using a little bit of XML.  Just leave all your annotated fields unspecified, and they'll get injected auto-magically.

Though just to be clear, I believe that you'll have to provide a setter for your Integer field.  Spring doesn't want to reach in directly and set fields via the XML descriptor.