# Injecting Properties using Spring & annotation @Value

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am trying to load a properties file into a Spring bean and then inject that bean into a class.

The only part I can't get to work seems to be using the *@Resource* reference.Can someone connect the last piece for me? I get a null value every time. Doesn't seem to want to inject the value.

[EDIT] - I originally thought using the *@Resource* was the best way but the proposed solution I found easier.

I saw this solution in another post:

**Reference Solution Link:** [Inject Property Value into Spring - posted by DON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317687/inject-property-value-into-spring-bean)

Credit to Don for the post but I just wasn't sure how to finish it with the *@Resource*.

**Debugging Results:**
The variable value `appProperties` is always null. It's not being injected.

**Spring Config.**
[image]

Sample Class:

```
package test;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.annotation.Resource;


public class foo {
    public foo() {}
    @Resource private java.util.Properties appProperties;
}
```

Based on the advice in the approved solution below. Here are the changes I made.

---

## Solution Update:

Spring Config:
[image]

Java Class:
[image]

Comment: What happens when you try your solution?

Comment: private @Resource Properties is a typo? have you tried @Resource private Properties? I am not sure it shouldn't work like this I just never seen the annotation not before the modifier.

Comment: @Skaffman - I get a null value. The variable value is not being binded and injected.

Comment: @abalogh Ya I switch the @Resource around but still no change.

Comment: Are you sure your foo bean is Spring-managed? is it explicitly defined in the appcontext or you are using component-scan?

Comment: @abalogh - No I don't have a spring-managed foo bean. Do I need to define the a Foo bean in order to have that value defined? I thought maybe with the @Resource annotation I wouldn't need to. I could inject my appProperties bean.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For your solution to work you would also need to make foo a Spring managed bean; because otherwise how would Spring know that it has to deal with any of your annotations on your class?

- You can either specify it in your appcontext xml as a bean with `..class="foo"`
- Or use `component-scan` and specify a base package which contains your `foo` class.

Since I'm not entirely sure this is exactly what you want (don't you want a .properties *file* to be parsed by Spring and have it's key-value pairs available instead of a `Properties` object?), I'm suggesting you another solution: Using the `util` namespace

```
<util:properties id="props" location="classpath:com/foo/bar/props.properties"/>
```

And reference the values inside your beans (also, have to be Spring managed):

```
@Value("#{props.foo}")
public void setFoo(String foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
}
```

EDIT:

just realized that you are importing `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext` in your class which is probably unnecessary. I strongly encourage you to read [Spring reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/overview.html#overview-dependency-injection) at least the first few chapters, because a) it's a great read b) you will find it much easier to understand Spring if the basics are clear.

Comment: Thanks abalough I will try that with the <util tag and component scan.  

Well what I want is simply to take a properties and inject the properties into the class. I was just unclear how to make it work with the annotations. I thought if the bean was loaded into the applicationContext I could use the annotations to read the bean from that. The missing piece is as you mentioned with the second bean i need to inject the value or component scan.

Comment: If I choose the first method of implementation not using the @Component with component-scan, I wouldn't use the @Value anymore correct because I would have to inject in the spring config?

Comment: Also note that the value you give inside @Value, "#{props.foo}" in the above example, should not contain dots for property KEY itself ("foo" in this example). I was migrating to use EL from old school way where my keys inside the property file were of the form a.b.c=xyz etc. And it failed. Whereas, say abc=xyz worked.

Comment: If you really do need the dots, then use the id[key] notation instead. example: app.billing.orderform=myorderform    then set up properties id with say appProps. So the @Value becomes   @Value("#{appProps['app.billing.orderform']}")   I know, ugly isn't it.

Answer (score 3):

Just one more solution using properties placeholder.

The spring context:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="your.packege" />

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:*.properties"/>

</beans>
```

The java class where you want inject properties values:

```
public class ClassWithInjectedProperty {

    @Value("${props.foo}")
    private String foo;
}
```