# Spring @Value with multimine properties file value

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

Spring (3.1): 
Given a property file with multi line value (of course the real value is much larger):

```
requestStatuses=select sysdate \
from dual
```

I have set up Spring as described:

```
<util:properties id="sql_lookup_data_repo"
     location="classpath:sql_lookup_data_repo.properties"/>
```

And used as described:

```
  @Value("#{sql_lookup_data_repo.requestStatuses}")
  public void setRequestStatuses(String requestStatuses) {
    this.requestStatuses = requestStatuses;
  }
```

At first sight it seems to be working BUT **only the first line of property value is read**.

When spring is starting up it is reading the file correctly (debugged).
It seems that it is lost when evaluating SpEL expression.

**Is it possible to use this spring functionality with multi line property file values and how?**

Already checked:

- [How to read values from properties file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259819/how-to-read-values-from-properties-file)
- [Injecting Properties using Spring & annotation @Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425795/injecting-properties-using-spring-annoation-value)
- [How can I inject a property value into a Spring Bean which was configured using annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317687/how-can-i-inject-a-property-value-into-a-spring-bean-which-was-configured-using)

Comment: I can use the multi-line property value in multiple places without any problems (the lines are, of course, concatenated). Please describe the exact failure scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

Multi line properties needs to have a backslash at the end of each line.

But if you have **space (invisible!) after the backslash** (before the newline) the evaluation will stop at that point.

(I am sorry but I could not make invisible characters visible in here :), so I could not provide example )

Warning: it is more about improper use of Java properties files! you can run into this problem without using @Value feature of Spring (plain `Properties.load()`).

Comment: That's hardly a problem with Spring - it's a mal-formed properties file.

Comment: Continued lines must end with \

Comment: Agree. It is just difficult to find becouse it is all about invisible characters.

Comment: RIght, but my point is that this question and your self-answer seems to point the blame at Spring when this is just the way java properties files work. Spring delegates to the JVM to load the properties. If they're not well formed, they're not well formed. Period.

Comment: Partially agree: from Spring `@Value` usable point of view (the way it is used in the source code) that expression can belong to any spring bean (not necessarily Properties). But in this case of course it is really my improper use of properties file. So I refrase the answere to reflect reality better.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me...

```
lines=foo \
bar \
baz
```

.

```
@Value("#{fooprops.lines}")
public void setMultiLine(String lines) {
    System.out.println(lines);
}
```

.

```
foo bar baz
```

Comment: Unbelievable: Today it is working fine. It might be just computer restart or clean compile.I do not know. Thank you very much.