# How to configure quartz scheduler with spring-style properties file in Tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, quartz-scheduler

I have a web application on Apache Tomcat. The web application uses the [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/). I load the `quartz.properties` from the classpath with the `-D` switch which contains the following properties:

```
quartz.jndi=java:comp/env/something
org.quartz.dataSource.myJndiName.jndiURL=${quartz.jndi}
```

But it isn't working. Maybe, the `${quartz.jndi}` only works in Spring Context with the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean? Is it possible to load this properties file in Spring for the Quartz Scheduler?

Answer (score 9):

Over a year later I know, but hopefully useful to somebody: you can accomplish this by setting the properties inside your Spring context xml:

```
<bean name="schedulerFactory" depends-on="flyway" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="quartzProperties">
        <map>
            <entry key="org.quartz.threadPool.class" value="org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool" />
            <entry key="org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties" value="true" />
            <entry key="org.quartz.jobStore.class" value="org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX" />
            <entry key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass" value="org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate" />
            <entry key="org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix" value="QRTZ_" />
            <entry key="org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource"  value="qzDS" />
            <entry key="org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.jndiURL" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/${jndi.dataSource}"/>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey">
        <value>applicationContext</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Notice I've put most of the JobStore-related properties in here as they seem to need to be in the same place. There is still some other configuration in the usual quartz.properties file.

Comment: It help me to solve the message **UpdateChecker [Quartz version update check failed: java.io.IOException:** every time the server started up. i added this `<entry key="org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck" value="true"/>`

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `configLocation` in your SchedulerFactoryBean:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:quartz.properties" />
    [...]
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what kind of Quartz property you want, there might already be a Spring-way of passing it. Generally for referring to properties entries (non Quartz-specific) pre and post Spring 3 [look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317687/inject-property-value-into-spring-bean). For Quartz-specific Spring setup and configuration have a look at the first part of the [Spring scheduling documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/scheduling.html).