# How to disable Quartz update attempt?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am using:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

When application comes up, I consistently get:

```
2013-01-03 15:25:34 UpdateChecker [DEBUG] Checking for available updated 
                        version of Quartz...
2013-01-03 15:25:43 UpdateChecker [DEBUG] Quartz version update check failed:
                        java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response 
                        code: 503 for URL: long url here
```

**How can I eliminate these? (Both the message and attempt to update)**

Comment: I wonder how many other libraries are doing version update checks. This is so awful.

Comment: Update check has been removed:
https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/commit/e1f78465fae7d3e81d30487f7f47697ec9a30d87#diff-322198a516a6b5e2cb61317c0b808831

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In `quartz.properties`, you can add

```
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck=true
```

In code, this would look like:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck","true");

// set other properties ...such as
props.setProperty("org.quartz.jobStore.class", "org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore");
props.setProperty("org.quartz.threadPool.class", "org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool");
props.setProperty("org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount", "4");

SchedulerFactory schdFact = new StdSchedulerFactory(props);
```

*Edit:*

From @Stephan202's comment below you can use the constant [PROP_SCHED_SKIP_UPDATE_CHECK](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/impl/StdSchedulerFactory.html#PROP_SCHED_SKIP_UPDATE_CHECK)

The code in that case would be

```
props.setProperty(StdSchedulerFactory.PROP_SCHED_SKIP_UPDATE_CHECK,"true");
```

Comment: I've given you an _all-code_ example here. You can load the properties in from the existing `quartz.properties` and add to them also.

Comment: The corresponding constant is `StdSchedulerFactory.PROP_SCHED_SKIP_UPDATE_CHECK`.

Comment: If using Spring framework and the SchedulerFactoryBean and you don't have (or want) a quartz.properties file, see this question/answer for how to set properties on Quartz in bean config: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403384/how-to-configure-quartz-scheduler-with-spring-style-properties-file-in-tomcat

Comment: I don't know why,but using that in default `quartz.properties` does not work for me, while loading it myself and passing as Properties does work.