# how to load spring properties without injection or inject a bundle or something?

Tags: spring

I currently load my properties file like so in spring

```
<context:property-placeholder location="test-esb-project-config.properties"/>
<context:property-placeholder location="esb-project-config.properties"/>
```

This seems to work great for properties use inside the xml files.  How do I load a property from inside my java code now though?  OR how do I inject some kind of Bundle or Config object so I don't have to inject 10 properties in one bean?

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Do u mean this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317687/inject-property-value-into-spring-bean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using annotations @Value(${property}) worked much better and it injected the property into my bean without all the work of xml typing and adding a setter...way too much work going that route.

Answer (score 0):

You can either have setters for each property and wire them with the property reference.

```
public class MyBean{
    public void setFoo(String foo){ /* etc */}
    public void setBar(String bar){ /* etc */}
}

<bean class="foo.bar.MyBean">
    <property name="foo" value="${my.properties.foo}" />
    <property name="bar" value="${my.properties.bar}" />
</bean>
```

Or you can inject a Properties Object into your Spring Bean.

```
public class MyBean{
    public void setProperties(Properties properties){
        // init your properties here
    }
}

<bean class="foo.bar.MyBean">
    <property name="properties" value="classpath:/path.to.properties" />
</bean>
```

Both of these would also work without XML when using the `@Value` annotation.
(see [Expression Language > Annotation-based Configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef-annotation-based))