# How to make a class a bean?

Tags: java, spring

I have a MongoService class

```
public class MongoService {

    private final Mongo mongo;
    private final String database;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MongoService.class);

    public MongoService(@Nonnull final String host, final int port, @Nonnull final String db) throws UnknownHostException {
        mongo = new Mongo(host, port);
        database = db;
    }

    public void putDocument(@Nonnull final DBObject document) {
        LOGGER.info("inserting document - " + document.toString());
        mongo.getDB(database).getCollection(getCollectionName(document)).insert(document, WriteConcern.SAFE);
    }

    public void putDocuments(@Nonnull final List<DBObject> documents) {
        for (final DBObject document : documents) {
            putDocument(document);
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    public <T extends DBObject> T getDocument(@Nonnull final T document) {
        final DBCollection collection = mongo.getDB(database).getCollection(getCollectionName(document));
        collection.setObjectClass(document.getClass());
        //noinspection unchecked
        return (T) collection.findOne(document);
    }

    @Nonnull
    public <T extends DBObject> List<T> getDocuments(@Nonnull final T document) {
        final List<DBObject> documents = new ArrayList<DBObject>();
        final DBCollection collection = mongo.getDB(database).getCollection(getCollectionName(document));
        collection.setObjectClass(document.getClass());
        final DBCursor dbCursor = collection.find();
        if (dbCursor != null) {
            documents.add(dbCursor.next());
        }
        //noinspection unchecked
        return (List<T>) documents;
    }
}
```

I want to create a singleton bean of this class which reads the host, int, port, database from the file

**Question**

How shall I go about achieving this?

- What are the best way to provide the configuration params from file
- How do I make it singleton bean?

I am new to Spring and don't really know how to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the values to the constructor as follows

```
<bean id="mongoService" class="MongoService">
  <constructor-arg name="host" type="java.lang.String" value="localhost"/>
  <constructor-arg name="port" type="long" value="1234"/>
  <constructor-arg name="db" type="java.lang.String" value="dbname"/>
</bean>
```

Note: This is Spring 3 syntax, older version doesn't support `name` parameter, just remove it.

If you want to further externalize the properties, you can do this.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="locations" value="jdbc.properties"/>
</bean>

<bean id="mongoService" class="MongoService">
  <constructor-arg name="host" type="java.lang.String" value="${host}"/>
  <constructor-arg name="port" type="long" value="${port}"/>
  <constructor-arg name="db" type="java.lang.String" value="${db}"/>
</bean>
```

Make sure jdbc.properties is in your classpath.

Entries in jdbc.properties

```
host=localhost
port=1234
db=dbname
```

EDIT: For you second question, this `mongoService` bean is by default Singleton.

Comment: can this be any other properties file than `jdbc.properties` and stay on the classpath?

Comment: yes, you can configure PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to load any properties file from classpath. In the above example, change the locations property.

Comment: fyi:  <constructor-arg with a name is unreliable.  Not all bytecode will contain the constructor arg names, only the types.  It's best to use the "index" attribute in combination with the name.  If a name can't be found it should use the index.  Also, the <constructor-arg syntax is verbose.   I prefer <bean ... c:_0="${host}" and so forth.

Answer (score 4):

Spring beans are singleton by default so..

```
@Service
public class MongoService
```

Check out [How can I inject a property value into a Spring Bean which was configured using annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317687/inject-property-value-into-spring-bean) for injecting properties, it's pretty nifty.