# Change spring bean alias with System property

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

I try to figure out whether it's possible to change a spring alias configuration through a system property.

That's the configuration:

```
<beans>
    <bean id="beanOne" ... />
    <bean id="beanTwo" ... />
    <bean id="beanThree" ... />
    <alias name="beanOne" alias="beanToUse" />

    <bean id="consumer" ...>
        <constructor-arg ref="beanToUse" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I'd like to be able to use a JVM property e.g. with `-Duse=beanThree` to select another bean for the alias.

Unfortunately using the straight forward solution `<alias name="#{systemProperties.use}" alias="beanToUse" />` throws a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` exception :(

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you check this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317687/inject-property-value-into-spring-bean

Comment: Yes I did but using properties to retrieve arguments themselves is not the problem here ... of course using that technic would enable to introduce a proxy which is then used instead of the alias - but as I said, that wasn't the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to use spring 3.1 profiles?

```
<beans>
    <bean id="beanOne" ... />
    <bean id="beanTwo" ... />
    <bean id="beanThree" ... />
    <beans profile="A">
      <alias name="beanOne" alias="beanToUse" />
    </beans>

    <beans profile="B">
      <alias name="beanTwo" alias="beanToUse" />
    </beans>

    <bean id="consumer" ...>
        <constructor-arg ref="beanToUse" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

and choose through system property `-Dspring.profiles.active=A`. I haven't tried aliases in profiles but you could just have alternative `beanToUse` definitions in each profile:

```
<beans>
    <beans profile="A">
      <bean id="beanToUse" ... defined as beanOne ... />
    </beans>

    <beans profile="B">
      <bean id="beanToUse" ... defined as beanTwo .../>
    </beans>

    <bean id="consumer" ...>
        <constructor-arg ref="beanToUse" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Btw. nice that in addition: `<beans profile="A,default"> ... </beans>` works as expected and finally leads to the behavior I intended. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do this using SpEL.
I have two implementations of DataStrategy type with bean ids testDataStrategy and realDataStrategy

I can choose between the beans by setting the property 'data.strategy' in the Property file in my Java project.

```
<bean id="myBeanId" class="com.some.path.MyBeanClass" >
    <property name="dataStrategy" value="#   {'${data.strategy}'.equalsIgnoreCase('TEST_DATA') ? testDataStrategy : realDataStrategy}" />
</bean>
```