# How can I select Spring bean instance at runtime

Tags: java, spring

Based on parameters passed to a method, I need to select from one of many Spring beans that are implementations of the same class, but configured with different parameters.

E.g. if user A invokes the method, I need to call `dooFoo()` on bean A, but if it's user B then I need to call the very same method, only on bean B.

Is there a 'Springier' way of doing this other than sticking all the beans in a map, and deriving a key from the parameters passed to my method?

Comment: A solution suggested by a colleague was that `@Autowired Map<String, BaseInterface>` will populate with bean ID as the key - perhaps that might be the least-worst solution.

Comment: Take a look at the similar post.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/24525715/3796723

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like do you want a `ServiceLocator` using the application context as registry.

See [ServiceLocatorFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ServiceLocatorFactoryBean.html) support class for creating ServiceLocators mapping keys to bean names without coupling client code to Spring.

Other option is to use a naming convention or annotation based configuration.

for example, assuming that you annotate Services with `@ExampleAnnotation("someId")`, you can use something like the following Service Locator to retrieve them.

```
public class AnnotationServiceLocator implements ServiceLocator {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;
    private Map<String, Service> services;

    public Service getService(String id) {
        checkServices();
        return services.get(id);
    }

    private void checkServices() {
        if (services == null) {
            services = new HashMap<String, Service>();
            Map<String, Object> beans = context.getBeansWithAnnotation(ExampleAnnotation.class);
            for (Object bean : beans.values()) {
                ExampleAnnotation ann = bean.getClass().getAnnotation(ExampleAnnotation.class);
                services.put(ann.value(), (Service) bean);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: can `checkServices();` method be called only once? in a constructor or init method?

Answer (score 14):

We face that issue in our project, and we solve it through a Factory-Like class. The client class -the one that needed the bean at runtime- had an instance of the factory, that was injected through Spring:

```
@Component
public class ImTheClient{

    @Autowired
    private ImTheFactory factory;

    public void doSomething(
            Parameters parameters) throws Exception{        
        IWantThis theInstance = factory.getInstance(parameters);        

    }

}
```

So, the `IWantThis` instance depends on the runtime value of the `parameters` parameter. The Factory implementation goes like this:

```
@Component
public class ImTheFactoryImpl implements
        ImTheFactory {

    @Autowired
    private IWantThisBadly anInstance;
    @Autowired
    private IAlsoWantThis anotherInstance;

    @Override
    public IWantThis getInstance(Parameters parameters) {
        if (parameters.equals(Parameters.THIS)) {
            return anInstance;
        }

        if (parameters.equals(Parameters.THAT)) {
            return anotherInstance;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

So, the factory instance holds reference to both of the posible values of the `IWantThis` class, being `IWantThisBadly` and `IAlsoWantThis` both implementations of `IWantThis`.

Comment: A nice one solution! :)

Answer (score 2):

Sticking them in a map sounds fine. If it's a Spring-managed map (using `util:map`, or in Java config), that's better than creating it somewhere else, because then Spring owns all the object references and can manage their lifecycle properly.

Answer (score -1):

If the beans (A, B) you are talking about are `SessionScope` its no problem at all, they will be selected correctly.

```
public class BusinessLogic {

  private BaseClassOfBeanAandB bean;

  public void methodCalledByUserAorB() {
    bean.doFoo();
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. There are no HTTP sessions in this case, and the beans are too heavyweight to instantiate per-request.

Comment: Then how can you differ between user A and B? Based on the parameter passed to the method?

Comment: Yep. There is some pre-authentication, so we get user IDs passed to us (actually several parameters that combine to create an identity, but that's beside the point).

Comment: Thanks for the downvote without cause. The OP did not state that there are no HTTP sessions, so how should I know my answer was not correct up to that point?