# SpringMVC: Variables in Annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, annotations

I have the following controller defined:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class MyController extends AbstractController
{

    @Autowired
    public MyController(@Qualifier("anotherController") AnotherController anotherController))
    {
     ...
    }

}
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to use variables in the @Qualifier annotation, so that I can inject different controllers for different .properties files, e.g.:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class MyController extends AbstractController
{

    @Autowired
    public MyController(@Qualifier("${awesomeController}") AnotherController anotherController))
    {
     ...
    }

}
```

Whenever I try I get:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No matching bean of type [com.example.MyController] found for dependency: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this 
dependency. Dependency annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=${awesomeController})
```

I've included the following bean in my config.xml file:

```xml
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:config/application.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But the bean doesn't work unless I declare the bean explicitly in the xml file.

How do I do this with annotations??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317687/how-can-i-inject-a-property-value-into-a-spring-bean-which-was-configured-using and http://springinpractice.com/2008/12/02/new-stuff-in-spring-30/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I think it is bad practice to make the dependency injection rely on configuration properties. You are probably going a wrong direction trying to do this.

However to answer your question: accessing placeHolder properties requires the dependency injection to be finished. To make sure it is, you can put your code that accesses the property inside a `@PostContruct` annotated method.

You will need to retrieve the bean manually from the applicationContext using `getBean()` method.

```
@Value("${awesomeController}")
private String myControllerName;

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
   AnotherController myController = (AnotherController) appContext.getBean(myControllerName);
}
```

Comment: I tried @ PostContruct on the constructor, but that was an invalid annotation placement, so I created a setter method:

@ PostConstruct
    @ Autowired
    public void set(
            @ Qualifier("${awesomeController}") AnotherController anotherController)
    {
      ...
    }

But I'm getting the following error:
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Lifecycle method annotation requires a no-arg method

Can you explain in more detail?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if what you're doing is possible but I can suggest a slightly different approach,  but only if you're using Spring 3.1+. You could try using Spring Profiles.

Define the different controllers you want, one per profile:

```xml
<beans>
    <!-- Common bean definitions etc... -->

    <beans profile="a">
        <bean id="anotherController" class="...AnotherController" />
    </beans>

    <beans profile="b">
        <!-- Some other class/config here... -->
        <bean id="anotherController" class="...AnotherController"/>
    </beans>
</beans>
```

Your Controller would lose the `@Qualifier` and become something like:

```
@Autowired
public MyController(AnotherController anotherController) {
    ...
}
```

Then at runtime you can specify which controller bean you want to use by activating the corresponding profile using a system property, e.g.:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active="a"
```

or:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active="b"
```

It may be possible to set profiles based on a property file but you can find out more about Spring Profiles from [this post](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/) on the Spring blog. I hope that helps somewhat.