# Using @Value annotation

Tags: spring

I have 2 property files **a.properties** and **b.properties**
I've added the to application context as:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:a.properties" />
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:b.properties"/>
```

First file with properties contains db connection details(this works well)
Second - contains properties that are used by some specific bean.
In that bean I use these properties via `@Value` annotation

```
@Value("#{qw.er}")
private String someA;    
@Value("#{as.df}")
private String someB;
```

However I get exception during startup:

```
 org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: 
EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'qw' cannot be found on object of type 
'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Is it possible yo use 2 `context:property-placeholder` in one file?

PS: Properties qw.er and as.df exist only in file b.properties

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317687/how-can-i-inject-a-property-value-into-a-spring-bean-which-was-configured-using). You can use `@Value("#{myProperties['github.oauth.clientId']}")`

Comment: actually, haven't understood what is `myProperties` in `@Value("#{myProperties['github.oauth.clientId']}")`

Comment: Sorry I've misunderstood your question. You can use `<util:properties id="config" location="classpath:b.properties" />` and then `@Value("#{config['as.df']}")` will be helpful. I will look for usage of `<context:property-placeholder` also. By the way, the error says Spring is looking for beans named qw/as and fields in them named er/df.

Comment: am I right? when using property-placeholder one should use ${} as placeholders, but not #{}

Comment: Yes it seems you are right. I've added an answer with a blog that explains mechanism.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is explained [here](http://www.baeldung.com/2012/02/06/properties-with-spring/)

After defining your properties you should use

```
@Value("${qw.er}")
private String someA;
```

Notice $ sign.