# How to dynamically specify version for dubbo @Service

Tags: java, spring

```
  @Service(version = "${spring.dubbo.application.version}")
```

I want to let the version here read from the profile, how to do it, thank you, I need help

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking a spring related question, so please check how to use `@Value` annotation of Spring from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699817/using-value-annotation), or you can leverage `Environment` class to read property from configuration file like `environment.getProperty("spring.dubbo.application.version")`.

Comment: I know what you are saying, sorry, I may not have made it clear that the `@Service` annotation here is provided by [Dubbo](http://dubbo.io/) and he does not support `@Value`. @kenshinji