# autowiring properties directly into bean using spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using `Spring3`. I have below `property` in one of the bean.

```
private Properties properties;
```

Here properties is `util` package property

```
    <bean id="properties" class="java.util.Properties">
            <constructor-arg>
                <props>
                    <prop key="id">${id}</prop>
                    <prop key="protocol">${protocol}</prop>
                    <prop key="username">${username}</prop>
                    <prop key="password">${password}</prop>
                </props>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>

    <bean id="propertyFactory"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:conf/test.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
           class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false"/>
        <property name="properties" ref="propertyFactory"/>
    </bean>
```

Now how can I inject properties directly from spring configuration?

Thanks!

Comment: You can do that using the solution given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317687/how-can-i-inject-a-property-value-into-a-spring-bean-which-was-configured-using

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access some property values, there is an elegant way.

In your context.xml file :

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:myfile.properties" />
```

In your class :

```
@Value("${key.property}")
private int myNumberProperty;

@Value("${another.key.property}")
private String myStringProperty;
```

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to configuring software using certain properties such as URL's, passwords and unique keys in spring [PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer) is your best bet.

From spring document:

```
You use the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to externalize property values from a bean definition in a separate file using the standard Java Properties format. Doing so enables the person deploying an application to customize environment-specific properties such as database URLs and passwords, without the complexity or risk of modifying the main XML definition file or files for the container.
```

What you will do is, put all your configuration data in a properties file:

```
##JDBC related properties start here##
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
jdbc.databaseURL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databaseName
jdbc.userName=root
jdbc.password=root  
##JDBC related properties end here##
## path Configuration start here##
path.name=mypath
path.type=httpfile
path.url=http://acdsds:8380/gis/
## path Configuration ends here##
```

Then, configure spring to access external properties file(assuming your properties file is named settings.properties):

```
<!--settings for accessing external property files--> 
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>                  
                <value>/yourPathToPropertiesFile/settings.properties</value>                   
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

After you have configured PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, access your properties by simple using @value annotation, wherever you want.

```
@Value("${path.name}")
String pathName;
```

You can use properties file to configure you data source and many other stuff:

```
<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.databaseURL}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>
```