# Can we add @Autowired on primitive setter method of a bean?

Tags: java, spring, autowired

Can we add `@Autowired` on primitive setter method of a bean?

How does `@Autowired` work for primitive?

Comment: Just try it.... What is it you want to inject?

Answer (score 0):

No, for primitive value use `@Value` annotation. `@Autowired` is looking for bean.

Read [How can I inject a property value into a Spring Bean which was configured using annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/317687/516167)

With Spring Boot this is even easier:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="connection")
public class ConnectionSettings {

    private String username;

    private InetAddress remoteAddress;

    // ... getters and setters

}
```

where values are configured in `application.yml`

```
connection:
    username: admin
    remoteAddress: 192.168.1.1
```