# How to programmatically define system property for spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot

I have spring boot applications deployed on AWS.  These applications have shared properties that are used to initialize database connection(`Autowired` properties), and they also have their own properties.

What we are doing now is setting application specific properties to `application.properties`.  And, we have a class, which is extended by the `Application` class, has a `static` piece to load all the properties from S3.

Here's the base application

```
public abstract class BaseApp {
    static {
        /*
        logic to read properties from S3, and set to System.property
        */
        final GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key);
        final S3Object s3obj = s3Client.getObject(request);
        final Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(s3obj.getObjectContent());

        for (final Object k : prop.keySet()) {
            System.getProperties().put(k, prop.get(k));
        }
    }
}
```

For each of the services,

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends BaseApp {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```

The problem here is, it also needs to connect to s3 when running UT code.  Is there any solution to let the `static` piece to run only in production environment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure dynamic properties while using spring boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28756014/how-to-configure-dynamic-properties-while-using-spring-boot)

Comment: If the class was a `@Component` or `@Configuration` then you could have used `@Profile("production")`. See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-profiles) for more details.