# Use main args with SpingBoot & velocity

Tags: java, spring, velocity, args

I am making a program and I need to read from main args but I don't know how to proceed.

**my code**

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**controller**

```
@Controller
public class SampleControler {

    @Autowired
    private Checker checker;

    @RequestMapping("/monitoring")
    String home(Model map)
    {
        try {
            map.addAttribute("donnee", checker.run(/*My main args has to be there*/);

            return "index" ;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            return "error";
        }
    }
}
```

Can you anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the [manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-command-line-args) you'll need to add command line arguments like

```
java -jar yourapp.jar --yourParam1=value1 --yourParam2=value2
```

to your application.

In your `SampleControler` you can access those arguments through the [Environment](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html):

```
@Controller
public class SampleControler {

    @Autowired
    private Checker checker;

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @RequestMapping("/monitoring")
    String home(Model map)
    {
        try {
            map.addAttribute("donnee", checker.run(environment.getProperty("yourParam1", "defaultValue"));

            return "index" ;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            return "error";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, use @Value annotations. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317687/how-can-i-inject-a-property-value-into-a-spring-bean-which-was-configured-using for some more info on the various ways of using that.

Comment: Hi guys ! Thanks for answering. In the run method parameter should be a Sting array ( args[]). Is that possible :S ?

Comment: You mean something like `java -jar myapp.jar --param1=value1,value2`?

Comment: Pretty like java -jar myapp.jar --param1=value1 --param2=value2 ...
I fixe my problem thx ;)