# In Spring, how can I autowire a property of a bean?

Tags: spring, properties, autowired

I’m using Spring 3.2.11.RELEASE.  I have the following bean …

```
<beans:bean id=“customAuthenticationFilter"
    class="org.mainco.subco.core.security.CustomAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_custom_value" />
    …
```

From within one of my Spring classes, I’d like to figure out the value of the “filterProcessUrl” property.  I could do something like

```
@Autowired
private CustomAuthenticationFilter myFilter

…
String value = myFilter.getFilterPRocessesUrl();
```

but I wanted to see if I could somehow outwore the “filterProcessesUrl” value into a member field (essentially boiling the above two lines of code into one).  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317687/how-can-i-inject-a-property-value-into-a-spring-bean-which-was-configured-using). Hope this Helps.

Comment: Yup, that exactly solves it.  Thanks!