# How can I parse.Float an application properties?

Tags: spring-boot

My current code when I use inputstream. prop = new properties;

```
 Application = prop.getProperty("Application");
 servers = prop.getProperty("SERVERS");
 username = prop.getProperty("USER_NAME");
 password = prop.getProperty("PASSWORD");
Float criticalThreshold = Float.parseFloat(prop.getProperty("THRESHOLD_CRITICAL"));
Float badThreshold = Float.parseFloat(prop.getProperty("THRESHOLD_BAD"));
```

I recently implemented my application properties into my java class using spring boots way.

```
@Value("${Application}")
private String Application;
@Value("${SERVERS}")
private String servers; 
@Value("${USER_NAME}")
private String username;
@Value("${PASSWORD}")
private String password;
```

But I do not know how to rewrite the Float.parseFloat

```
    Float criticalThreshold = Float.parseFloat(prop.getProperty("THRESHOLD_CRITICAL"));
Float badThreshold = Float.parseFloat(prop.getProperty("THRESHOLD_BAD"));
```

I tried but it automatically gives me an compiler error.

```
@Value("${THRESHOLD_CRITICAL}")
    private Float criticalThreshold;
@Value("${THRESHOLD_BAD}")
    private Float badThreshold;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Value` lets you specify a method to call to alter the injected property:

```
@Value("#{T(java.lang.Float).parseFloat('${THRESHOLD_CRITICAL}')}")
private float criticalThreshold;
```

I tested it and it also works without the full package name:

```
@Value("#{T(Float).parseFloat('${THRESHOLD_CRITICAL}')}")
private float criticalThreshold;
```

Comment: sorry, fixed it (need to specify the whole package), prefixed with T

Comment: seems like a good way of doing it, but still debugging, not working here

Comment: uhm... both ways are working for me. Can you show me your stacktrace ?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'THRESHOLD_CRITICAL' in string value "#{T(Float).parseFloat('${THRESHOLD_CRITICAL}')}"

Comment: And can you show your application.properties (in your question)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127396/discussion-between-javaguy-and-alex).

Answer (score 2):

**You can refer the solution suggested by Alex as it does not require the additional variable like in the below approach.**

You can't directly do that, but you can achieve that `@PostConstruct` and declaring one more variable `criticalThresholdFloatValue` like below:

```
@Value("${THRESHOLD_CRITICAL}")
private String criticalThreshold;

private float criticalThresholdFloatValue;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    criticalThresholdFloatValue = Float.parseFloat(criticalThreshold);
}
```

Now, you can start using `criticalThresholdFloatValue` where ever you are using in the bean methods.

Comment: Would it be possible to annotate the a setter method like in this example?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317687/how-can-i-inject-a-property-value-into-a-spring-bean-which-was-configured-using

Comment: Joe: I am not sure how to do that, but my approach above works, but needs additional var.