# How to initialize a bean basis on propertiy file boolean key value pair

Tags: spring

I am new to spring, Is there any way to initialize spring bean using property file key-value pair;

; if like my `config.properties` file contains `isSetup = true;`

then only initialize, `<bean id="a" class="com.Setup"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this post
[How can I inject a property value into a Spring Bean which was configured using annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317687/how-can-i-inject-a-property-value-into-a-spring-bean-which-was-configured-using)

This link can also help you : http://springinpractice.com/2008/12/02/new-stuff-in-spring-30/

You can pass the property as below  to bean :

```
<bean id="a" class="com.Setup"/>
    <property name="isSetup " value="#{systemProperties.isSetup }"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: thanks for you reply; here the requirement is basis on isSetup flag; I have to initialize Setup class.