# Auditing Spring User Level Context Data with JPA Events @PrePersist and @PreUpdate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have the below JPA Entity and I would like to use the @PrePersist and @PreUpdate to facilitate the setting of the lastUpdatedBy String with the current user from the Spring context, but I don't know how I can access that information from an entity level context. Any ideas?

```
public abstract class BaseEntity {
  private Date createdDate;
  private String lastUpdatedBy;

    @Column(name = "LAST_UPDATED_BY")
    public String getLastUpdatedBy() {
        return lastUpdatedBy;
    }

    public void setLastUpdatedBy(String lastUpdatedBy) {
        this.lastUpdatedBy = lastUpdatedBy;
    }

  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @Column(name="CREATED_DATE")
  public Date getCreatedDate() {
    return createdDate;
  }

  public void setCreatedDate(Date created) {
    if (created != null) {
      this.createdDate = created;
    }
  }


  @PrePersist
  protected void onCreate() {
    createdDate = new Date();
    //lastUpdatedBy =  //need to access Spring user here
  }

 @PreUpdate
    public void onUpdate() {
      updatedDate = new Date();
      //lastUpdatedBy =  //need to access Spring user here
    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191569/good-way-to-access-spring-singleton-from-within-domain-objects.<br/>
But are you sure you can't do that in your `@Service` or `@Repository` in a less "hidden" way?

Comment: @bellabax - it does seem like there are two approaches, one is JPA annotations and the other is SPRING Data annotations.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is that this problem seems to be resolvable using a function in your DAO (like `updateXXX(BaseEntity xxx,String updateBy)`) instead of listener to be more clear about `lastUpdateBy` lifecycle and don't hide it (is an application concerns, it lives as external info respect BaseEntity). I hope to be clear, nothing to do with spring/jpa annotation

Comment: @bellabax - my goal was to abstract this type of logic into the entity.  Setting the user information in the service or dao layer is certainly doable.  I just wondered if there was a way to do it without having to pass the updatedBy String between the layers, but it sounds like more headache than its worth

Comment: You don't mention Spring Security, but if that's how you're authenticating users you can access the user straight from the current thread using `SecurityContextHolder` ...

Comment: Not using Spring Security, but thanks for the input...helpful to those using it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution can be the one as defined in [Good way to access Spring singleton from within domain objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191569/good-way-to-access-spring-singleton-from-within-domain-objects.%3Cbr/%3E) to access Spring context.
In your context define a `CurrentUserHolder` bean defined as singleton bean accessed in @Pre/@Post functions using [`ApplicationContext.getBean()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean(java.lang.Class)).
 `CurrentUserHolder` bean contains the current user name and its value is mantained from application (can be setted after startup or after user changing).
It's a common solution in Spring-batch to pass data across steps.

Hope can help.