# Spring interceptors using @configuration

Tags: java, spring

I'v mostly used XML based configuration for applicationContexts. I have a requirement where I need to use @configuration to create my beans using @Bean now.

**Brief description of why ?**

weblogic deploys a spring web-app "A". A makes calls to B(not spring,not web app-no WEB_INF). B just contains common service calls to external servers. Hence B.jar is bundled into A and A is then deployed on web-logic.
Now i need to use spring beans in B.)

**So the options available at this point:**

1. Bundle applicationContext.xml and all the property files into B.jar. (keep in mind it is a very complex build process with 20 property files and 100s of beans. So I also need to register propertymanager bean etc..). Then initialize appcontext in a static initializer block and look for appcontext within B.jar.
2. Use @configuration to register an Appconfig.class instead of an XML. (no changes to build process here).

With this option i need to use a clientInterceptor. Could you provide me with the @Bean definition of this.
How do I configure clientInterceptor in @appconfig.class.

*please let me know if there any other options.

- Spring-ws-core - 2.1.4.release
- spring-core-3.2.4
- expression,context,beans - 3.0.5
- spring-oxm-1.0.3
- weblogic - 12c
- jdk - 1.7

This is my first post here. Any suggestions would be welcome and appreciated. Apologize for any forum faux paus.

Comment: hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310271/injecting-beans-into-a-class-outside-the-spring-managed-context) helps.

Comment: kind of. But specifically i wanted a way to use MVC interceptors using @configuration.