# How to add POJO to Spring context to enable injecting dependencies?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, pojo

I have a class that would otherwise be a very generic POJO but I would like to inject a dependency in it because I would like to avoid passing that dependency as a (constructor) parameter:

```
//no managed context annotation because it's a simple POJO
public class QueuedBatch {

    //however, I would like to inject the context managed bean below
    @Autowired
    AsyncActionQueue asyncActionQueue;
```

Currently, no exception is thrown at deploy time but `asyncActionQueue` is null at runtime so I get a `NullPointer` when I hit the POJO.

How can I annotate my POJO to add it to the Spring managed context so that I can inject dependencies into it?  `AsyncActionQueue` is a singleton and I would rather not be passing it to `QueuedBatch` as a (constructor) parameter.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310271/injecting-beans-into-a-class-outside-the-spring-managed-context) is similar, except that I want to add my POJO into the managed context.

Comment: Annotate it as a @Component; it's not under Spring's control as written.  If you call new to create it, then Spring knows nothing about it either.

Comment: are you saying annotate `QueuedBatch` as a `@Component` ?

Comment: *Don't* avoid passing a constructor parameter. If it's a required dependency, don't hide it.

Comment: Normal objects that are not annotated for Spring use aren't managed by Spring. So Spring knows nothing about them and so you can't directly inject a bean into an unmanaged class. The use of [`@Component`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html) will be useful here.

Comment: Yes I am.  I would also advise you to rethink  your "rather not be passing it ...as constructor parameter".

Comment: when I annotated it as `@Component`, the autowired object was still null

Comment: I agree with @duffymo here, there is no real reason why you should avoid passing an `Object` as a parameter in the constructor to a class that Spring doesn't care about.

Comment: In the interest of full disclosure, using `new` in an `@Bean` will autowire fields. Field injection is still a Bad Thing.

Comment: as per the suggestions, I injected the dependency via the constructor and kept my POJO outside the Spring managed context

Comment: Either all the pieces are under Spring's control or none of them are.  You can't ask Spring to inject into POJO beans that you create by calling new.

Comment: Better pass it using constructor rather than @Autowired. I feel POJO should not have any logic other than setters and getters, but its upto the developers only :)

Comment: autowiring in a non-spring managed class isn't allowed. it is only spring managed classes

Answer (score 2):

As the comments suggested you have 2 ways of dealing with this

1. Pass the AsyncActionQueue as a parameter in the constructor of QueuedBatch. This doesnt require Spring to know anything about QueuedBatch, but enforces the dependency to be provided when an instance of QueuedBatch is created.
2. Annotate the QueuedBatch class with @Component. And ensure that the package which contains QueuedBatch is included in the component scan when initializing the spring context. In this way, it becomes a spring managed bean allowing AsyncActionQueue to be autowired into it. You may change the scope of QueuedBatch component based on your requirement.