# How to inject dependency into RabbitListener

Tags: java, spring

The following class handle the messages receive on a Rabbit MQ channel:

```
@RabbitListener(queues=RabbitMQConfiguration.QUOTE_REQUEST_QUEUE)
public class QuoteRequestHandler {

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessageSendingOperations messagingTemplate;

    @RabbitHandler
    public void handle(String request) {
        QuoteChannelServiceImpl.getInstance(messagingTemplate);
    }

}
```

I'd like to have access to `SimpMessageSendingOperations` inside this class, but as it is not a spring bean, it'd be null. I'm wondering if there is a clean way to inject this dependency into this class.

Comment: Why don't you make it spring bean? AFAIK `@RabbitListener` won't work if it is not spring bean.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add POJO to Spring context to enable injecting dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39353019/how-to-add-pojo-to-spring-context-to-enable-injecting-dependencies)

Comment: @talex I checked for few examples and I cannot confirm what you said, e.g. https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-spring-amqp.html

Comment: In your example `ReceiverConfig` class add `Tut2Receiver` to spring context.

Comment: If I annotate it with `@Service` does it mean it will be in Singleton scope and for all message in the queue, the same handler will be used?

Comment: And is it normally how rabbit listener seems to work?

Comment: Yes for both questions.