# How to Autowire a class at runtime in a method

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to Autowire fields in a dynamic class?
I am getting a class name from the database and I want to autowire this class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure it's a good idea, but you can inject a class like mentionned here :
[Injecting beans into a class outside the Spring managed context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310271/injecting-beans-into-a-class-outside-the-spring-managed-context)

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer**

That's not possible. Spring needs to know what Beans there are for injecting them.

**Long Answer**

You could `@Autowire` every possible bean into a class and then cache them in a Map, where the Class represents the key, and the Object the value. See below simplified example:

```
public class MyClass{
     private final Map<Class<?>, Object> cache = new HashMap<>();

     @Autowired
     public MyClass(Service1 s1, Service2 s2){
         // registering the beans
         cache.put(Service1.class, s1);
         cache.put(Service2.class, s2);
     }

     public <T> T getService(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException{
         // getting the bean
         Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
         return (T) cache.get(clazz);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Component
public class ApplicationContextAccessor {

private static ApplicationContextAccessor instance;

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

public static  T getBean(Class clazz) {
    return instance.applicationContext.getBean(clazz);
}

@PostConstruct
private void registerInstance() {
    instance = this;
}
```

}

Read this post : https://www.helicaltech.com/uses-of-springs-applicationcontext-while-using-reflection/