# Can't get Spring Boot + JavaFX running in Eclipise

Tags: java, spring-boot, javafx

I'm trying to get Spring Boot working with Java FX according to [this tutorial](http://mfjassociates.blogspot.com/2019/02/tutorial-on-how-to-write-and-run-javafx.html). Specifically I cloned and tried to run [this project from the tutorial](https://github.com/marioja/javafx/tree/master/mfx11boot), which is supposed to be set up correctly.

When I try to run the project in Eclipse with Run as / Spring Boot App, I get the following error:

`Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application`

I'm running JDK 11 and I tried adding the javafx jars to the build path according to the tutorial. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you are having problem getting something to run, start with something simpler, like HelloWorld using JavaFX (no Spring, no IDE) as demoed in [this guide](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).  Once you have that working, then move on to trying to [get JavaFX working in Eclipse](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx).  Only once you have that working, try to add in Spring.

Comment: See also a related question on: [Adding Spring Dependency Injection in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57887944/adding-dependency-injection-in-javafx-jpa-repo-service/57896435#57896435)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to adding the JavaFX libraries to build path, you also have to edit the run configuration and add `--add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml` to the VM arguments.

Saw that when reading [the official guide](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven) again based on @jewelsea's comment.