# how to configure javafx with springboot with more than 1 window?

Tags: java, spring, javafx, null

I have problem.
This is my main:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
public class MyAppSpringApplication extends Application {

    public static ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;
    private FXMLLoader fxmlLoader;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/sample.fxml"));
        Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
        stage.setTitle("Sample app");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        springContext.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        springContext = SpringApplication.run(MyAppSpringApplication.class);
        fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(springContext::getBean);
    }
}
```

And my first window (sample.fxml) with samplecontroller and sampleservice works ok. But i create another `dish-builder.fxml` with their contoller and service, but when i try to use my service there, it doesnt work because of null in dishbuilderservice (albo doesnt work sampleservice in that new controller). I heard that i shound also use that:

```
public static ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;
```

but i have no idea how should i use it. Sorry for my weak knowledge and english.

```
     @Controller
    public class DishBuilderController implements Initializable {
    
        @Autowired
        DishBuilderService dishBuilderService;
    
        @Autowired
        SampleService sampleService;
    
        private void somefun(){
            sampleService.somefunInService(); //here sampleService and 
        every other service has null.

}
```

Here is the moment when i open new dishBuilder window (its in SampleController):

```
@FXML
    void addNoweOknoClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            Stage stage = (Stage)anchorPane.getScene().getWindow();
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
            fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/dish-builder.fxml"));
            AnchorPane root = fxmlLoader.load();
            stage.setTitle("Sample app");
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show the code where you load `dish-builder.fxml`

Comment: You need to load the second FXML the same way you load the first, if you want spring to inject components into the controller

Comment: So i should just copy that first page start, init, stop and paste in samplecontoller? And also adnotate it as @springbootapplication?

Comment: How would that work? `start()`, `init()`, and `stop()` are only called on the Application instance.

Comment: I had no idea, so i ask :P Now works, thanks for the time

Comment: But surely you understand the code *you* posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load `dish-builder.fxml` you are not setting the controller factory on the `FXMLLoader`. This means the `FXMLLoader` is simply creating the controller by calling its no-arg constructor. Since the controller is not a spring-managed bean, spring cannot inject any components into it.

You need to set the controller factory, as you do when you load `sample.fxml`, so that the `FXMLLoader` will ask Spring to retrieve the controller from the application context.

A couple of points that are not strictly relevant to your question:

- There is no need to expose the `ApplicationContext` as a public static field. You can inject it into any spring-managed beans that need access to it
- It is not recommended to re-use `FXMLLoader`s.  Therefore there's no point in making the `FXMLLoader` an instance variable.
- The `@Controller` annotation is intended for *web* controllers in a Spring MVC application. These are quite different to controllers in the JavaFX sense. You should use a generic `@Component` annotation for JavaFX controllers.
- In the event that you were to reload an FXML file, you would need a new controller instance. This means that if the controller is managed by Spring, it needs to have `PROTOTYPE` scope, instead of the default `SINGLETON` scope.

So you need:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyAppSpringApplication extends Application {

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(springContext::getBean);
        fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/sample.fxml"));
        Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
        stage.setTitle("Sample app");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        springContext.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        springContext = SpringApplication.run(MyAppSpringApplication.class);
    }
}
```

Then your `SampleController` should look like

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class SampleController {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext ;

    @FXML
    void addNoweOknoClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            Stage stage = (Stage)anchorPane.getScene().getWindow();
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
            fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(springContext::getBean);
            fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/dish-builder.fxml"));
            AnchorPane root = fxmlLoader.load();
            stage.setTitle("Sample app");
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and similarly

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class DishBuilderController implements Initializable {

    @Autowired
    DishBuilderService dishBuilderService;

    @Autowired
    SampleService sampleService;

    private void somefun(){
        // this should now work, since the controller is managed by Spring:
        sampleService.somefunInService();   
    }

}
```

Comment: Works!! Thanks for that answer <3

Comment: One potential source of confusion with this answer is that two instances of `MyAppSpringApplication` will be created, by the JavaFX [`Application.launch`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html#launch(java.lang.String...)) method and another by the Spring [`SpringApplication.run`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html#run-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String...-) method.  Also, the spring run method is not passed the command line arguments.

Comment: There is some discussion on addressing the argument passing and instance management in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57896435/1155209), though that answer is not perfect, there are numerous confusing subtleties involved and well-integrating a JavaFX and SpringBoot application.