JavaFx and Springboot program isn't switching scenes
I've been trying to learn settings up a program using javafx and springboot. I have primarily used github examples to get started with learning how to do this, if there's an easier way please let me know.
I've been successful in getting the program to start up and launch the initial fxml page. However after clicking a button I want to be able to switch scenes. This is where I'm having a program. Essentially whenever I click the 'Login' button nothing happens. I'm not given an error or anything.
Launcher.java
public class Launcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       FxApplication.main(args);
       // javafx.application.Application.launch(FxApplication.class, args);
    }


}

FxApplication.java
`@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.gaitlabapp.repo")
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses={FxApplication.class, UserLoginController.class})
public class FxApplication extends Application {

    private static Optional<ConfigurableApplicationContext> SPRING_CONTEXT = Optional.empty();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        fireStartUpEvent(new StartUpEvent(stage));
    }

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception{
        super.init();
        SPRING_CONTEXT = Optional.ofNullable(SpringApplication.run(FxApplication.class));
        start();

    }
    private void fireStartUpEvent(ApplicationEvent event){
        SPRING_CONTEXT.ifPresentOrElse(context -> context.publishEvent(event), () ->{
        });
    }

    private void start(){
        SPRING_CONTEXT = Optional.ofNullable(SpringApplication.run(FxApplication.class));
    }`

StartUpListener.java
@Component
public class StartUpListener implements ApplicationListener<StartUpEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(@NonNull StartUpEvent event) {
        try {
            new UserLoginController(event.getStage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

StartUpEvent.java

`public class StartUpEvent extends ApplicationEvent  {
    public StartUpEvent(Stage stage ) {
        super(stage);
    }
    public Stage getStage(){
        return (Stage) getSource();
    }
}`

UserLoginController.java
@FxmlView("UserLogin.fxml")
public class UserLoginController implements Initializable {

@Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        loginButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                try {
                    login(event);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }

 public UserLoginController(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        try {
            Stage stage1 = new Stage();
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(Launcher.class.getResource("/UserLogin.fxml"));

            fxmlLoader.setController(UserLoginController.class);
            Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();

            stage.setTitle("Login");
            stage.setWidth(450);
            stage.setHeight(250);

            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.setResizable(false);
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

@FXML
    public void login(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Launcher.class.getResource("/PatientModule.fxml"));
        loader.setController(PatientModuleController.class);
        root = loader.load();
        stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setTitle("Patient Module");
        stage.setHeight(750);
        stage.setWidth(1050);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        alertTimer = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.hours(1), event1 -> {
            showAlert();
        }));

    }
}


UserLogin.fxml
<AnchorPane prefHeight="196.0" prefWidth="475.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/20.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"  >
            <children>
                <TextField fx:id="nameTextField" layoutX="234.0" layoutY="68.0" />
                <Button fx:id="loginButton" layoutX="133.0" layoutY="152.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="176.0" text="Login" />
                <Label layoutX="71.0" layoutY="68.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="110.0" text="Username">
                    <font>
                        <Font size="20.0" />
                    </font>
                </Label>
      <TextField layoutX="234.0" layoutY="116.0" />
      <Text layoutX="71.0" layoutY="36.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Welcome to the Gait Lab!">
         <font>
            <Font size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
      <Label layoutX="71.0" layoutY="110.0" prefHeight="37.0" prefWidth="110.0" text="Password">
         <font>
            <Font size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
            </children>
</AnchorPane>

Before implementing Springboot, I had the fx:controller listed within the FXML document and had an onAction listed within the  fxml tag. I set the controller within the UserLoginController class through the setController function. I also edited the loginButton.setOnAction to implement a login method to switch scenes. That doesn't work either. So I found a stack overflow about using the @ComponentScan on the FxApplication.java file and that also hasn't changed anything. I'm wondering if I possibly do not have the controller initialized properly. Does the @Component tag need to applied to each controller file that I'm using?

It's really unclear what a lot of this code is doing. Can you at least clean it up and remove all the obviously redundant code? (E.g. you have a private void start() {} which is never called, a Stage stage1 = new Stage(); which is never used, etc. etc.). Unless I am missing something, there is no component in UserLogin.fxml that has login() as its event handler. When are you expecting login() to be called?

"Before implementing Springboot, I had the fx:controller listed within the FXML document and had an onAction listed within the fxml tag" Why did you change it? "I set the controller within the UserLoginController class through the setController function." This call is clearly wrong: the controller should be an actual controller instance, not an instance of Class<?>.

I clean it up but the login() is being called via the loginButton.setOnAction within the initialize function in the UserLoginController.java file. Again I can clean this up - I had a lot of confusion on how to set up this project to be non-modular so perhaps the example I found on github wasn't the best.

@James_D - I changed it because I was receiving the following error -  Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Controller value already specified.

There is a simple example of what you are trying to do here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72510142/how-to-configure-javafx-with-springboot-with-more-than-1-window See also this, which is linked in a comment to the answer to that question.

"Controller value already specified" This means you have (or had) both the fx:controller attribute specified and you were calling setController(...) on the FXMLLoader. Again, there is no obvious need for the latter call.

It's also unclear why you are loading the FXML file in the controller. Typically in JavaFX this is done the other way around: you load the FXML and the FXMLLoader creates the controller instance. There are reasons and mechanisms for reversing the usual flow of control, but it's really not clear why you are doing so here.

@James_D - even if I removed the setController() I would still get an error -- Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javafx.fxml.LoadException:
/C:/dev/GaitApp/target/classes/UserLogin.fxml:10

Well that's a different error. So clearly it means you have fixed the previous error. Honestly, this code just looks like you have made random guesses at what is causing the errors and have just copied and pasted code you've found online without actually understanding what it does. You cannot possibly learn to program like that. I'd recommend starting over, copy only the parts that make sense from your existing code, and slowly build up the functionality you want, testing with each addition. Don't use code you don't understand.

The actual reason that nothing is happening is that the controller for UserLogin.fxml is set to UserLoginController.class, which is an instance of Class<?>. The controller for UserLogin.fxml is not an instance of UserLoginController (either the existing one or a new one). Class does not have an initialize() method, and you don't specify an event handler for loginButton, so there is no handler invoked when you press the button. But again, I don't know (and I strongly suspect you don't know) why you have set things up like this.

@James_D - this was such an easy fix once I deleted everything and just started over. All the extra stuff I didn't understand just made my life harder in trying to understand what I wanted to do. I got it working as intended with the fx:controller and the onAction methods in the  tags. So thank you for telling me I didn't understand cause it forced me to just understand.
