# How do you add an externally instantiated object to Dagger?

Tags: kotlin, javafx, dagger-2

I'm using JavaFX, where you create a class that extends JavaFX `Application`, and then you pass the class to JavaFX's `launch` method. Inside the `Application` class you override the `start` method which gets an instance of `Stage` passed into it.

How can I make this instance of `Stage` available as a dependency for other objects?

```
// Kotlin

fun main() {
    launch(MyApplication::class.java)
}

class MyApplication : Application()
{
    override fun start(stage: Stage)
    {
        // I want other objects to be able to have stage injected into them.
        val myWindow = MyWindow
        stage.run {
            scene = Scene(myWindow, 800.0, 600.0)
            show()
        }
    }
}
```

In Spring I think you would do something [like this](https://theholyjava.wordpress.com/2011/10/11/spring-make-an-externally-created-object-available-to-beans-in-applicationcontext-xml/)

```
// Java

Object externalyDefinedBean = ...;
GenericApplicationContext parentContext = new StaticApplicationContext();
parentContext.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton("injectedBean", externalyDefinedBean);
```

Comment: Note that typically you don't need to provide the stage to other objects, as it's usually accessible via the scene graph from objects that are "naturally" available. E.g. in a JavaFX controller you have access to scene graph elements injected via `@FXML`, and you can always navigate from such a node via calls such as `node.getScene().getWindow()`. Injecting a `Stage` into other parts of your application is a bit of a code smell.

Comment: I know you can get stage in other ways, but this an example where I want to know how you would do it anyways. I don't have a better example for asking this question with regards to Dagger.

Comment: Fair enough; accessing the `HostServices`, for example, is a reason to need this. I don't know Dagger; I have seen this done in Spring and Guice.

Comment: There is a discussion of how to do something similar with Spring in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57887944/adding-spring-dependency-injection-in-javafx-jpa-repo-service/57896435#57896435), I also do not know the Dagger analog.  The linked answer for Spring is a bit different in that it injects auto wired dependencies into the application rather than making the application an injectable managed bean (which I am not sure would be a good idea in any case).

Comment: [Gluon ignite](https://gluonhq.com/labs/ignite/) has a dagger implementation.  You might want to check its source to see if it does what you want (I don't know if it will or not).