# spring with javafx exception when load fxml

Tags: java, spring, javafx

Maybe the question is stupid. But I haven't worked with JavaFX before, so I'm asking for help.
I tried to create an application that allows you to create a document by clicking on the button.But when I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
2023-11-06T10:52:27.409+05:00  INFO 17156 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Starting application using Java 17.0.2 with PID 17156 (started by днс in E:\MaximDocuments)
2023-11-06T10:52:27.412+05:00  INFO 17156 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-11-06T10:52:27.486+05:00  INFO 17156 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Started application in 0.454 seconds (process running for 1.741)
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/E:/MaximDocuments/target/classes/mainWindow.fxml:10

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2727)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:946)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:983)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:230)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:757)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2858)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2654)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2568)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2536)
    at documents.JavaFxApplication.start(JavaFxApplication.java:32)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:839)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:483)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'documents.controller.MainWindowController' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:332)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1176)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:943)
    ... 17 more
```

Here are my classes:

mainWindow.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="documents.controller.MainWindowController">
    <top>
        <HBox spacing="10" padding="10">
            <Button text="Счет" onAction="#handleInvoiceAction"/>
            <Button text="Платежка" fx:id="paymentButton" onAction="#handlePaymentAction"/>
            <Button text="Заказ на оплату" fx:id="paymentOrderButton" onAction="#handlePaymentOrderAction"/>
            <Button text="Сохранить" fx:id="saveButton" onAction="#handleSaveAction"/>
            <Button text="Загрузить" fx:id="loadButton" onAction="#handleLoadAction"/>
            <Button text="Просмотр" fx:id="viewButton" onAction="#handleViewAction"/>
        </HBox>
    </top>
    <center>
        <VBox spacing="10" padding="10">
            <ListView fx:id="documentListView" />
        </VBox>
    </center>
    <bottom>
        <HBox spacing="10" padding="10" alignment="bottom_right">
            <Button text="Выход" fx:id="exitButton" onAction="#handleExitAction"/>
        </HBox>
    </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

MainWindowController:

```
package documents.controller;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import documents.model.DisplayableDocument;
import documents.model.Invoice;
import documents.model.Payment;
import documents.model.PaymentOrder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Controller
public class MainWindowController {

    private DisplayableDocument currentDocument;
    @FXML
    private void handleInvoiceAction(ActionEvent event) {
        loadWindow("/invoice.fxml", "Счет");
    }

    @FXML
    private void handlePaymentAction(ActionEvent event) {
        loadWindow("/payment.fxml", "Платеж");
    }

    @FXML
    private void handlePaymentOrderAction(ActionEvent event) {
        loadWindow("/paymentOrder.fxml", "Платежное поручение");
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleSaveAction(ActionEvent event) {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        fileChooser.setTitle("Сохранить документ");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Text Files", "*.txt"));
        File selectedFile = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow());

        if (selectedFile != null) {
            saveDocumentToFile(selectedFile);
        }
    }

    private void saveDocumentToFile(File file) {
        if (currentDocument == null) {
            return;
        }
        try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file)) {
            if (currentDocument instanceof Invoice invoice) {
                fileWriter.write(convertInvoiceToString(invoice));
            } else if (currentDocument instanceof Payment payment) {
                fileWriter.write(convertPaymentToString(payment));
            } else if (currentDocument instanceof PaymentOrder paymentOrder) {
                fileWriter.write(convertPaymentOrderToString(paymentOrder));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private String convertInvoiceToString(Invoice invoice) {
        return String.format(
                "Invoice,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s%n",
                invoice.getId(),
                invoice.getNumber(),
                invoice.getDate(),
                invoice.getUser(),
                invoice.getAmount(),
                invoice.getCurrency(),
                invoice.getCurrencyRate(),
                invoice.getProduct(),
                invoice.getQuantity()
        );
    }

    private String convertPaymentToString(Payment payment) {
        return String.format(
                "Payment,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s%n",
                payment.getId(),
                payment.getNumber(),
                payment.getDate(),
                payment.getUser(),
                payment.getAmount(),
                payment.getEmployee()
        );
    }

    private String convertPaymentOrderToString(PaymentOrder paymentOrder) {
        return String.format(
                "PaymentOrder,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s%n",
                paymentOrder.getId(),
                paymentOrder.getNumber(),
                paymentOrder.getDate(),
                paymentOrder.getUser(),
                paymentOrder.getContractor(),
                paymentOrder.getAmount(),
                paymentOrder.getCurrency(),
                paymentOrder.getCurrencyRate(),
                paymentOrder.getCommission()
        );
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleLoadAction(ActionEvent event) {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        fileChooser.setTitle("Загрузить документ");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Text Files", "*.txt"));
        File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow());

        if (selectedFile != null) {
            loadDocumentFromFile(selectedFile);
        }
    }

    private void loadDocumentFromFile(File file) {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.startsWith("Invoice:")) {
                    Invoice invoice = parseInvoice(String.valueOf(reader));
                } else if (line.startsWith("Payment:")) {
                    Payment payment = parsePayment(String.valueOf(reader));
                } else if (line.startsWith("PaymentOrder:")) {
                    PaymentOrder paymentOrder = parsePaymentOrder(String.valueOf(reader));
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private Invoice parseInvoice(String line) {
        String[] data = line.split(",");

        return new Invoice(
                Integer.parseInt(data[1]),
                data[2],
                LocalDate.parse(data[3]),
                data[4], 
                new BigDecimal(data[5]),
                data[6], 
                new BigDecimal(data[7]),
                data[8],
                Integer.parseInt(data[9])
        );
    }

    private Payment parsePayment(String line) {
        String[] data = line.split(",");

        return new Payment(
                Integer.parseInt(data[1]),
                data[2],
                LocalDate.parse(data[3]),
                data[4],
                new BigDecimal(data[5]),
                data[6]
        );
    }

    private PaymentOrder parsePaymentOrder(String line) {
        String[] data = line.split(",");

        return new PaymentOrder(
                Integer.parseInt(data[1]),
                data[2],
                LocalDate.parse(data[3]),
                data[4],
                data[5],
                new BigDecimal(data[6]),
                data[7],
                new BigDecimal(data[8]),
                new BigDecimal(data[9])
        );
    }


    @FXML
    private void handleViewAction(ActionEvent event) {
        loadWindow("/documentDetails.fxml", "Детали документа");
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleExitAction(ActionEvent event) {
        cancel(event);
    }

    private void loadWindow(String path, String title) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(path));
            Parent root = loader.load();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setTitle(title);
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void cancel(ActionEvent event) {
        Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }
}
```

ApplicationRunner:

```
package documents;

import javafx.application.Application;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ApplicationRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(JavaFxApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

JavaFxApplication :

```
package documents;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

import java.io.IOException;


public class JavaFxApplication extends Application {

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(ApplicationRunner.class);
        String[] args = getParameters().getRaw().toArray(new String[0]);
        this.context = builder.run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/mainWindow.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(context::getBean);

        try {
            Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.setTitle("Main Window");
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void stop() {
        this.context.close();
        Platform.exit();
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.maxim.documents</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestMaximDociments</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>22-ea+16</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>22-ea+16</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.30</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org/maxim/documents/JavaFxApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I tried using other fxml files, but the error is the same.
Adding a scheme, but it didn't help either.
I read that the problem can occur if you use constructors. I tried to implement this through the fields, but the error didn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to run the wrong `ApplicationRunner`.

You have a class named `documents.ApplicationRunner` but instead you import `org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner` from Spring and try to use that to initialize your application.  Your own `ApplicationRunner` is in your own package and initializes all the beans in the package and subpackage by default, but the `ApplicationRunner` from Spring doesn't know about your package and won't do that.

To prevent confusion I recommend calling your `ApplicationRunner` something different (I used `MySpringApplication` in the example below but you could use some name specific to your application if you wanted).

**Reference**

Futher info on this topic is provided in the answer here:

- [Adding Spring Dependency Injection in JavaFX (JPA Repo, Service)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57887944/adding-spring-dependency-injection-in-javafx-jpa-repo-service/57896435#57896435)

**Working Code**

To create this, I created a new JavaFX project in Idea, removed the generated `module-info.java` to make the project non-modular (Java modularity and Spring 6 mix poorly unfortunately).  Downloaded and extracted the JavaFX 21 SDK from Gluon.  Right clicked on the class `MySpringApplication` to choose "More Run/Debug: Modify the Run Configuration..." set the VM parameters of the run configuration as:

```
--module-path /Users/<username>/Downloads/javafx-sdk-21/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

I modified the code to call your spring application `MySpringApplication` and import and use that in your `JavaFXApplication`.

I removed all of the references to missing classes (most of that stuff is probably better handled in a service layer rather than in the Controller class anyway).

I changed the database dependency to h2 from postgres so I didn't have to setup postgres.

I removed the lombok dependency as I have seen other experienced developers note issues with it when used in the context of JavaFX and also recommend against its use in general.

I modified the fxml so that it would load (it defined insets incorrectly, so I deleted those references).

An FXML controller is not a Spring controller, which is for use in a Java Servlet style framework, don't annotate your FXML controller with the Spring `@Controller` annotation, a `@Component` annotation with `prototype` scope is probably best. (I used the recommended annotations in my example).

Don't use the JavaFX versions with `ea` in the name, they are early access versions, which may not be stable.  (I used a stable version - 21 - in my example).

**Outstanding issue**

There is another likely issue with your code, which I didn't try to address.  Although you correctly set the controller factory to use the spring context to inject Spring bean references into the controller when you load the main window FXML:

```
fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(context::getBean);
```

You don't set the controller factor for subsequent page loads which you perform in the `MainWindowController.loadWindow` method.  This means that none of these subsequent page loads will have spring beans injected into their related controllers.

I'll leave fixing this outstanding issue as an exercise for the reader ;-)

**Working Source Code**

*src/main/java/documents/MySpringApplication.java*

```
package documents;

import javafx.application.Application;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MySpringApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(JavaFxApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

*src/main/java/documents/JavaFxApplication.java*

```
package documents;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

import java.io.IOException;


public class JavaFxApplication extends Application {

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(MySpringApplication.class);
        String[] args = getParameters().getRaw().toArray(new String[0]);
        this.context = builder.run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/mainWindow.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(context::getBean);

        try {
            Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.setTitle("Main Window");
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void stop() {
        this.context.close();
        Platform.exit();
    }
}
```

*src/main/java/documents/controller/MainWindowController.java*

```
package documents.controller;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import static org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE;

@Component
@Scope(value=SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class MainWindowController {

    @FXML
    private void handleInvoiceAction(ActionEvent event) {
        loadWindow("/invoice.fxml", "Счет");
    }

    @FXML
    private void handlePaymentAction(ActionEvent event) {
        loadWindow("/payment.fxml", "Платеж");
    }

    @FXML
    private void handlePaymentOrderAction(ActionEvent event) {
        loadWindow("/paymentOrder.fxml", "Платежное поручение");
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleSaveAction(ActionEvent event) {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        fileChooser.setTitle("Сохранить документ");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Text Files", "*.txt"));
        File selectedFile = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow());

        if (selectedFile != null) {
            saveDocumentToFile(selectedFile);
        }
    }

    private void saveDocumentToFile(File file) {
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleLoadAction(ActionEvent event) {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        fileChooser.setTitle("Загрузить документ");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Text Files", "*.txt"));
        File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow());

        if (selectedFile != null) {
//            loadDocumentFromFile(selectedFile);
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleViewAction(ActionEvent event) {
        loadWindow("/documentDetails.fxml", "Детали документа");
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleExitAction(ActionEvent event) {
        cancel(event);
    }

    private void loadWindow(String path, String title) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(path));
            Parent root = loader.load();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setTitle(title);
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void cancel(ActionEvent event) {
        Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }
}
```

*src/main/resources/mainWindow.fxml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="documents.controller.MainWindowController">
    <top>
        <HBox spacing="10">
            <Button text="Счет" onAction="#handleInvoiceAction"/>
            <Button text="Платежка" fx:id="paymentButton" onAction="#handlePaymentAction"/>
            <Button text="Заказ на оплату" fx:id="paymentOrderButton" onAction="#handlePaymentOrderAction"/>
            <Button text="Сохранить" fx:id="saveButton" onAction="#handleSaveAction"/>
            <Button text="Загрузить" fx:id="loadButton" onAction="#handleLoadAction"/>
            <Button text="Просмотр" fx:id="viewButton" onAction="#handleViewAction"/>
        </HBox>
    </top>
    <center>
        <VBox spacing="10">
            <ListView fx:id="documentListView" />
        </VBox>
    </center>
    <bottom>
        <HBox spacing="10" alignment="bottom_right">
            <Button text="Выход" fx:id="exitButton" onAction="#handleExitAction"/>
        </HBox>
    </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

*pom.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.maxim.documents</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestMaximDociments</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>21.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>21.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org/maxim/documents/JavaFxApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Output**

[image: output]

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.4)

2023-11-06T14:35:38.053-08:00  INFO 27963 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Starting application using Java 21.0.1 with PID 27963 (started by <username> in /Users/<username>/dev/documents)
2023-11-06T14:35:38.056-08:00  INFO 27963 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-11-06T14:35:38.493-08:00  INFO 27963 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-11-06T14:35:38.530-08:00  INFO 27963 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 26 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-11-06T14:35:38.865-08:00  INFO 27963 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-11-06T14:35:39.118-08:00  INFO 27963 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:mem:28b3894c-1aa7-4d13-9a1d-5afed0a7ada6 user=SA
2023-11-06T14:35:39.120-08:00  INFO 27963 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-11-06T14:35:39.177-08:00  INFO 27963 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-11-06T14:35:39.253-08:00  INFO 27963 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.2.9.Final
2023-11-06T14:35:39.255-08:00  INFO 27963 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000406: Using bytecode reflection optimizer
2023-11-06T14:35:39.424-08:00  INFO 27963 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2023-11-06T14:35:39.614-08:00  INFO 27963 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2023-11-06T14:35:39.787-08:00  INFO 27963 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2023-11-06T14:35:40.055-08:00  INFO 27963 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-11-06T14:35:40.060-08:00  INFO 27963 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-11-06T14:35:40.346-08:00  INFO 27963 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Started application in 2.629 seconds (process running for 3.963)
```