# Accessing the Spring Service from another Magnolia Module (Not using Spring Blossom)

Tags: magnolia

I'm not sure if this is Magnolia specific question. But anyways, I have a custom action for my content app where I want to call a Spring Service from other Magnolia Module which does not use the Spring Blossom Module.

How will I be able to call the Spring service and make sure that all the autowired beans inside it are working?

Thanks :)

Comment: Just initialize your beans as you would for any other webapp that is using Spring. Do you have actually real problem that something is not initialized with the configuration you have or are you just speculating that it might not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that this is not actually Magnolia related question.
I found the solution from [Getting Spring Application context from a non bean object without using Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475785/getting-spring-application-context-from-a-non-bean-object-without-using-singleto) for this case.

Thanks!