# Web Console for Spring Application Context

Tags: java, spring, web-applications

Is there a way to expose my Spring applicationContext via a servlet or webapp so that I can manipulate and inspect the beans in the appcontext.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at the [Spring Inspector](https://github.com/julior/spring-inspector) a plug-gable component that provides programmatic access to any Spring based application at run-time. You can use Javascript to change configurations or manage the application behavior at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

Not aware of a special tool/plug-in. Maybe this would do:

[How can I determine Objects in application context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713943/how-can-i-determine-objects-in-application-context)

Answer (score 0):

[Spring Insight](http://static.springsource.com/projects/tc-server/6.0/devedition/) might do the trick.

Comment: Its a start.  I don't need to debug the appcontext.  I need to manipulate it. i.e turn services off and on without doing a restart.