# Right path to applicationContext.xml using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing

I have working web-application with applicationContext.xml in WEB-INF/config/applicationContext.xml. Now i need to implement some testing tool as standalone application, that can use the same applicationContext.xml, but have problem with path to config for ClassPathXmlApplicationContext class.

I know that when i copy applicationContext.xml to default package (where .java resides) i can use ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml"), but is this necessary ?

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class AdminTool {

    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    /** all below doesn't work - FileNotFoundException) **/
    private static final ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/WEB-INF/config/applicationContext.xml");
    private static final ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config/applicationContext.xml");
    private static final ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("../config/applicationContext.xml");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AdminTool();
    }

    public AdminTool() {
        log.debug(ac);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In a local test scenario, you are not inside a Jar, so you don't need Classpath-based access. Use [`FileSystemXmlApplicationContext`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.html) instead.

Probably something like this:

```
private static final ApplicationContext ac =
    new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(
        "src/WEB-INF/config/applicationContext.xml"
    );
```

(paths are relative from the execution directory)

Comment: I was thinking about running my AdminTool using webapp.war. Will it be possible using FileSystemXmlApplicationContext ?

Comment: @marioosh No, in a war you have the same problems as in a jar: there are no files, just entries. Is the war deployed to a servlet container or local?

Comment: @Patrick I would like to use AdminTool class from .war without deploying. PS: I have maven project: new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/config/applicationContext.xml"); works when i run AdminTool in Eclipse

Answer (score 3):

This is the reason why I prefer to put all configuration files in *classes* folder. In fact, using Maven, you can put all these files in *src/main/resources*. Then, in your test files you can access as '*classpath:applicationContext.xml*'.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static final ApplicationContext ac =
    new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(
        "/WEB-INF/config/applicationContext.xml"
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final ApplicationContext ac =
new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(
    "/WEB-INF/config/applicationContext.xml"
);
```

Comment: Please explain why the below code having issues compared with above code.

Answer (score -1):

please go to property>Java Build Path>Source of your project check the classpath and add the directory before WEB-INF in the classpath. definitely it's work