# How to get Spring Context

Tags: java, spring, callback

I have a third party library that starting up my aplication, load spring context and save it in private static filed without any acessors.

I need to get this context to my application. Does spring provides some callbacks like afterContextLoaded methods or any other ways how to get it?

Reflection is not a solution for me!

Thanks.

Comment: similar thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129207/getting-spring-application-context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have several ways to archive that:

1. Use ApplicationListerner and ApplicatinEvent
2. Use ApplicationContextAware

Both of them can be found at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch03s13.html
(sorry for the link is not to the latest version)

Answer (score 1):

Just implement [ApplicationContextAware](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html) in a Spring bean.

If you want to access the AppContext on startup, then also implement [InitializingBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html) and put your code in [afterPropertiesSet()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html#afterPropertiesSet%28%29) - the ApplicationContext instance will be populated and ready for use at that time.