# Getting Singleton Bean Instance From Spring Container

Tags: java, spring

How can I get existing singleton instance of a bean from Spring Container.
I do not want to load the config again as follow but want to retrieve the bean created already using this config;

```
ApplicationContext context =  new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("some.xml");
```

Thanks in advance for early attention.

Comment: And ... did you try to read the doc or just type `spring tutorial` in google ?

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129207/getting-spring-application-context) maybe this helps.

Comment: If your bean is declared/annotated to be singleton - which ist the default [scope](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_bean_scopes.htm) - then getting it from your BeanFactory/Context using its id should be enough.

Comment: yes but not found suitable answer.

Comment: That is way there is a little thing called dependency injection.

Answer (score 1):

Here an Example

```
public class MyFancyBean implements ApplicationContextAware {

  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
  }

  public void businessMethod() {
    //use applicationContext somehow
  }

}
```

Here you go:

```
applicationContext.getBean("someName")
```

Note that there are tons of ways to start Spring - using ContextLoaderListener, @Configuration class, etc.