# How to access the bean, Once I define the ApplicationContext.xml

Tags: java, spring

I was using the ApplicationContext as follows to access my beans:

```
ApplicationContext context = 
             new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
 StudentJDBCTemplate studentJDBCTemplate = 
      (StudentJDBCTemplate)context.getBean("studentJDBCTemplate");
```

now I want to Create an applicationContext.xml and there I am using component-scan as follows:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.manager.*" />
```

so that I don't have to create ApplicationContext object to access the bean, and put it under my WEB-INF folder as explained [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/web-integration.html)

My question is, How do I access my beans now? Since there is no ApplicationContext Object at my disposal now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Spring Application Context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129207/getting-spring-application-context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @Autowired annotation. For that

1. Add `<context:annotation-config/>` into your applicationContext.xml so that annotation driven configuration is enabeled.
2. Add @Component annotation right before the class definition, where you need to inject your StudentJDBCTemplate instance.
3. Add @Autowired annotation right before of the attribute definiton of StudentJDBCTemplate.

for examle

```
@Component
public class MyClass {

    @Autowired
    private StudentJDBCTemplate studentJDBCTemplate;

    // here you can implement a method and use studentJDBCTemplate it's already injected by spring.
}
```

I hope it helps.