# Can I define ApplicationContext as a constructor-arg in Spring XML configuration?

Tags: spring

If I need access to the `ApplicationContext` in the constructor of my bean class is there a way I can configure the bean in XML rather than implementing `ApplicationContextAware`?

Note: I know I can do this using annotation-driven configuration and marking the constructor with `@Autowire`. I'm specifically interested in whether it's possible with XML configuration.

Comment: You can try with `<constructor-arg ref="applicationContext"/>` but not sure if that works. I wouls say `@Autowired` is the only way. I would like to note btw, that the need for the `ApplicationContext` would raise a red flag on my part because generally you don't want or need this.

Comment: Well, I generally agree but the thing I'm working on is a small library that integrates something with Spring so it's totally appropriate to tie it to Spring concepts.

Comment: `<constructor-arg ref="applicationContext"/>` doesn't work, sadly.

Comment: This works using configuration class instead of XML ... so I guess there should be a way to make it works in XML also. Did you get any advance on this?

Comment: I need the same.. Don't know how to get it.. :(

Answer (score 1):

The need to

> access to the ApplicationContext in the constructor of my bean class

is already "bad"...: [[1]](https://spring.io/understanding/application-context) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/143229/592355) (please primarily try to get rid of this need/change your mind!:)

Of course, `ref="applicationContext"` would be nice, but it doesn't work/noone knows how, ...but this "sledgehammer" approach can overcome: [[3]](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2007/03/accessing-spring-beans-from-legacy-code.html) (2007...mmmhk, ..."the wheel" is even older....;)

..a "singelton application context wrapper bean", which you can (constructor-) inject (almost;) everywhere. (As in xml, as in java config.)

ApplicationContextWrapper.java:

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;

/**
*  Thx to: http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2007/03/accessing-spring-beans-from-legacy-code.html
**/
public class ApplicationContextWrapper implements ApplicationContextAware {
  /** the original post has static variable and get-method, but within spring context,
  * and clean initialisation&wiring, it can be oblet.**/
  private /*static*/ ApplicationContext CONTEXT;

  @Override
  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
    CONTEXT = context;
  }

  public /*static*/ ApplicationContext getContext() {
    return CONTEXT;
  }
}
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="myWrapper" class="[some.package.]ApplicationContextWrapper"/>

<bean id="myCtxtDependentBean" class="[some.package.]CrazyBean" >
   <constructor-arg ref="myWrapper" />
</bean>
```

CrazyBean.java:

```
public class CrazyBean {

    public CrazyBean(ApplicationContextWrapper wrapper) {
        ApplicationContext ctxt = wrapper.getContext();
        // do crazy stuff here :)
    }

    // or in a static variant, just:
    public CrazyBean() { // ...no arguments, no injection
       ApplicationContext ctxt = ApplicationContextWrapper.getContext();
       // but ensure setApplicationContext's been called...
    }
}
```