# how to instantiate spring data jpa repository without autowired

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I have my repository interface as

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<Tokens, Long>{
}
```

and the service impl file in where I want to use above repository is not a 
@Component or @Service because its object is created using new. So it is not allowing autowiring or injecting the repository in my service impl class.

Is there any other way around to implement in such case?

Comment: Why did you use new instead of autowiring in the object which needs access to the repository?

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to use a JNDI lookup to get a managed instance of the `MyRepository`? I did that with EE beans in Pojos, but I never tried it within Spring. But I would assume, there is no difference in doing so.

Comment: Pass in the application context to the constructor of the `new` class.  Then you can pull the `Repository` from the context, using `.getBean` method.

Comment: You might be able to get the `Repository` instance by getting it from the application context using one of the static methods.  Refer to this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129207/getting-spring-application-context  However, why don't you have your service properly managed by Spring? you can have a wrapper object to do that, if the code using `new` is not yours or difficult to refactor. If you don't use the framework as intended it will work against you instead of giving you its dependency injection advantages.

Comment: I think there's a better way of doing this rather than instantiating a new Service.  Why can't you autowire this Service?

Comment: I am creating serviceimpl() object using new because this is a sdk and developers using this sdk can instantiate service impl using new as well. So I just want to handle both the cases (autowired and new).

Comment: going from using "new" to going via JNDI - that escalated quickly

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of options available.

First of all, you can use it as a normal dependency and use a factory bean to instantiate your object.

```
@Component
public class MyFactoryBean {

    private Repository repository;

    @Autowired
    public MyFactoryBean(Repository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public Instance getInstance(Parameter parameter) {
        return new Instance(repository, parameter);
    }
}
```

If your `parameter` does not change at runtime, you can provide a bean in your configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    private Repository repository;

    @Autowired
    public MyConfiguration(Repository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Bean 
    public Instance instance(){
        Parameter parameter = ... // value in a config file or static value 
        return new Instance(repository, parameter);
    }
}
```

Also, you can use the `AutowireCapableBeanFactory` to inject dependencies as normal for objects not managed by Spring. Remember that you need to use setter injection tough.

```
private AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

@Autowired
public MyFactoryBean(AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
    this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
}

public void doStuff() {
    MyService service = new MyService();
    beanFactory.autowireBean(service); // dependencies will be autowired
}
```

Comment: I did not know `AutowireCapableBeanFactory` existed.  Thanks for teaching me something new!

Comment: I don't understand your answer or how it would solve the problem.

Comment: can I use the "new" keyword?