# Call Spring component from Java code

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have this Spring component which I want to call from several locations in Java web application:

```
@Component
public class NotificationListener {

    public void notificationProcess(TransactionsBean ro) {

        // some code
    }    
}
```

Can I use it as a normal object in Spring or I should use other way to call the Spring code?

Comment: It's just a class, and doesn't seem to have any dependencies, so you could easily `new` an instance up and call its methods outside of any Spring context. Did you try that? What happened?

Comment: Note that if you do call it from outside of the application context, any autowiring will *not* take place.

Comment: ok, is there a way to call it as a component?

Comment: What do you mean *"as a component"*? What do you mean *"as a normal object"*? It's not clear to me what the problem is.

Comment: If the other code that wants to call on this object is also within Spring components, then you would just @Autowire a reference to this one from those others.  If the code is outside Spring components, then this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129207/getting-spring-application-context

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is retrieve the current `ApplicationContext` by implementing `ApplicationContextAware` and lookup the bean yourself with `getBean`.

Another thing you can try is autowire like you're used to with `@Autowired` and then use the following utility from Spring:

`SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);`